# Calling MySQL database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I am new to programming and trying to call a table from a MySQL database using Java.  Here is what my Java code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
        double p1[] = {10000000,2,5,7,5,6,6,8,9,3};
        double p2[] = {100,3,4,3,4,1,2,5,1,5};
        double p3[] = {1,2,6,4,5,6,7,8,9,1};
        Expert_Score x = new Expert_Score(a, p1);
        Expert_Score y = new Expert_Score(b, p2);
        Expert_Score z = new Expert_Score(c, p3);
        Z_score scrCalc = new Z_score();
        scrCalc.Z_Calc(x,y,z);
        scrCalc.print();
}
}
```

I want to be able to call from MySQL: a, b, c, p1, p2 and p3. a,b and c represent Customer ID's. P1, P2, and P3 represent a string of ten numbers from a table associated with those Customer Id's. I also want to deposit the output of this code back into a new table in MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to learn how to do [JDBC (Java DataBase Connectivity)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) with MySQL. Download [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (MySQL Connector for Java) and follow an article such as [this](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381/Using-JDBC-with-MySQL-Getting-Started.htm) which shows you a step-by-step approach on setting up MySQL and how to play with MySQL in java.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After you've done everything recommended here, I suggest you find and download the commons-db package from Apache.  It has a lot of utility classes and methods that will help you reduce the amount of code you have to write and keep things much simpler for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JDBC (Java Database Connectivity) API plus the appropriate JDBC driver for MySQL.

[Here's a page](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/) with the JDBC driver links plus tutorials etc.